# SQLIte insertion looping through text

Tags: jquery, sqlite, loops

I am trying to import some pieces of a long text into SQLite table but I have the following problem.

I use the bellow code in order to read the long text stored in a test DB.

```
var mycollectoridlength = 0, mybill, line =  0;

notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
      t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM billtest;', [], function(t, bulkdata){
           mybill = bulkdata.rows.item(0);
```

and then loop through long text and try to insert some pieces of it into another DB.

```
for (i = 1; i <= ((mybill.testtext.length)/126); i += 1) {

     alert(line) // alerts 1, 126, 252 ... 

     t.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE into buildings (buildingcode, buildingaddress, buildingcollect, buildingpay) VALUES (?,?,?,?);',
          [mybill.testtext.substr((line+0), 5).trim(), mybill.testtext.substr((line+44), 40).trim(), 0, 0], function(){

          alert(line) // alerts 10962 (87 *  126)
     });   


     line = i * 126;
}
```

but the line inside executeSql is not sync with the loop. The SQLite insertion executed after the loop. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you care about the `alert()`, which is in an asynchronous callback, and not about the data in the database?

Comment: unfortunately the db is empty...